# VS2019 without Windows 8.1 SDK

Tags: sdk, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to run an already functional application that requires the Windows 8.1 SDK.

I installed Visual Studio 2019, but there is no option in the 8.1 SDK.

This is for a Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2019 last update.

On my old computer, there was the option to select in "Individual Components", but now no longer the encounter. Does anyone know if there is no such support on VS2019? Or is it necessary to install something more for the support to appear?

Comment: were you able to install the 8.1 SDK from my link?

Comment: Thanks @magicandre1981. I upgraded the project to the newer version!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is expected as it is [marked as deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#-deprecations) in Visual Studio 2019:

> The Windows 8.1 SDK is no longer available in the Visual Studio
>   installer. Please upgrade your C++ projects to the latest Windows 10
>   SDK. If you have a hard dependency on 8.1, you can download it from
>   the Windows SDK archive.

So download and install the SDK from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive).